# Doxygen multi line comments

Tags: c++, doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I am new to Doxygen and trying to comment my code.

I have some issue with the comments: my multi line comments appear in a single line and I don't want to use `\\n` or `<br>`.

```
/** 
Brief - this is a function  
Get -  
Return -  
*/  
void func1()
{
    return
}
```

I want each line to start a new line.

However, the result is:

```
Brief - this is a function Get: - Return: - Post: -
```

I have tried also:

```
/// Brief - this is a function
/// Get -
/// Return -  
void func1()  
{
    return
}
```

Same result as mentioned above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The doxygen comments in that case are meant to ignore the implicit new lines so the text wrapping doesn't affect the output like

```
/** This is a long comment that caused the
IDE to wrap the text and therefore
span onto multiple lines **/
int func(bool b) {
}
```

but in your example I think you should use appropriate commands if each line of your doxygen has a semantic meaning like parameters, return values, etc.

```
/**
\brief This is a description of my function
\param[in] b This is some bool argument of my function
\return This describes the int that is returned in this case
**/
int func(bool b) {
}
```

See the [list of available commands here](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmd_intro).